# using encodeURI to display an entire page

Tags: google-chrome, xss, urlencode

Hi I am making a chrome extension. Where I save a page to the database as a string and then open it later as a `dataURI` scheme like:

```
d = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8'+encodeURI('HTML TEXT')
location.reload(d);
```

The problem with this is that the page, say its name is `http://X/`, in which I executed the above command loses the javascript files in its head.
I considered using the `document.write(d)`, if d has a string appeneded to it with the `<head>...</head>` of `http://X/`.

But this opens a big vulnerability problem for XSS. At this point I am trying to think of white listing tags when I save the original page... is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `http://X/`, but if want copied website to retain its origin (i.e. have code you give run exactly as if it were downloaded from `http://X/`), then I'm afraid it's not possible with standard DOM methods (it would be a security vulnerability that bypasses same-origin security policy).

If you want to run 3rd party sourcecode safely, then use this:

```
<iframe sandbox src="data:…"></iframe>
```

You could modify the source and insert `<base href="http://X/">` in there to make relative URLs work properly.